# 'istanbul' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, windows-7, istanbul

I have just added the [istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul) test coverage module to my node.js application, but when I run (from command prompt):

```
> instanbul cover myTests.js
```

as mentioned in the documentation, I get:

```
'istanbul' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I am under Windows 7. The npm installation returned no error. I see nothing in the documentation about extra installation steps.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you install it globally (with `-g` option)? Is your node installation dir in PATH variable?

Comment: No, I did not use the -g option... Let me try again

Comment: It works... If you create the solution, I'll approve it...

Comment: Just a note, it is istanbul not instanbul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a module to be runnable from anywhere, you need to install it globally (with `-g` option).

Answer (score 5):

The problem I see with this is when you move the project to a different server. Istanbul will need to be installed again globally. This defeats the npm model of package management. Another way to achieve this is to:

```
npm install --save-dev istanbul
```

Modify package.json script entries:

```
scripts: {

    "coverage": "node ./node_modules/.bin/istanbul ...."
}
```

Then call it using:

```
npm coverage
```

A shortcut for your local machine is also to set your environment path to include node executables:

export PATH=$PATH:./node_modules/.bin

In which case, any executables installed to your  package will be available on the command line automatically because of path checking.